# Why groovy Script behaves differently?

Tags: groovy

I'm new to groovy, so sorry if its an obvious question

Consider the following: have two files, Main.groovy and script.groovy

Main.groovy:

```
package org.example

static void main(String[] args) {
    def script = new GroovyShell().parse(new File('scripts/script.groovy'))
    println script.script
    println script.rScript()
}
```

script.groovy:

```
@groovy.transform.Field
String script = 'heredd'

String rScript() {
    return "${script}"
}
```

when I run Main.groovy, I see the following output:

```
heredd
class script
```

So, as I understand, when we get property `script` from Script object, it expectedly returns the value of the property. But when we try to access the property in a method inside the script - we actually reference the class `script` instead of the property. How to change the behaviour, so that calling `script.rScript()` would actually return `heredd`?

Comment: you have class name (script name), and variable with name `script`. renaming `script.groovy` to `Script.groovy` should resolve the issue.

Comment: another option `new GroovyShell().parse(new File('scripts/script.groovy').Text)` - this will generate random unique class name for your script like `Script_723498`.